# Spectrogram C++ library

Tags: c++, fft, scientific-computing, spectrum, spectrogram

For my current project in C++ / Qt I need a library (LGPL is preferred) which can calculate a spectrogram from a signal ( basically an array of doubles ). I already use Qwt for the GUI part.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: LGPL because you don't want to release source code?
I know FFTW libraries can be used under alternative licence than the GPL version.

Comment: try to search on sourceforge site something about "digital signal processing". AFAIK on that site was some libraries..

Comment: @gregseth, Did you finish this project? I have to do the same project and calculate a spectrogram from an array of doubles. I don't know how to start. Could you give me some hints. Merci

Comment: OpenCv is really nice library for that purposes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It would be fairly easy to put together your own spectrogram. The steps are:

1. window function (fairly trivial,
   e.g. Hanning)
2. FFT (FFTW would be
   a good choice but if licensing is an
   issue then go for Kiss FFT or
   similar)
3. calculate log magnitude
   of frequency domain components
   (trivial: log(sqrt(re * re + im *
   im))

Comment: Since log(sqrt(x)) = (1/2)log(x), you can make it run faster without sqrt()

Comment: @DarenW -- indeed - since we are typically working with dB then instead of doing 20*log10(sqrt(x)) we can just do 10*log10(x).

Comment: @PaulR , Could you please explain a bit more then how should I plot this data ? I mean I have followed your steps but now I am stuck? How do I plot this data ? I know spectrogram has frequency on Y-axis and time on X-Axis and Amplitude is shown by the intensity of color, but how do I plot it after getting step 3.

Comment: @KhubaibAhmad: the answer to that would be specific to whatever OS, programming language, and graphics API you are using. But essentially you just want a suitable colour palette and then map your magnitudes to indices in the palette.

Answer (score 12):

["How do I create a frequency vs time plot?"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/how-do-i-create-a-frequency-vs-time-plot) lists several libraries, each of which can calculate a spectrogram from a signal.

Copied and pasted from my own answer:

Some source code to generate [spectrograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) / [waterfall plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_plot) from audio data:

- [SoX - Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) includes [spectrogram source code](http://sox.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=sox/sox;a=blob;f=src/spectrogram.c;h=962199a7007dc42ecd8d2d4f6d60741d96687a53;hb=HEAD)
- [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) includes [spectrogram source code](https://code.google.com/p/audacity/source/browse/audacity-src/trunk/src/Spectrum.cpp)
- [glfer](http://www.qsl.net/in3otd/glfer.html) includes waterfall spectrum display spectrum source code
- source code that uses fftw to compute the [spectrogram](http://ofdsp.blogspot.com/2011/08/short-time-fourier-transform-with-fftw3.html) of an audio stream
- more source code that uses OpenAL and fftw to compute the [spectrogram](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~alexs/classes/2010_Spring_575/HW/HW5/OpenAL/alsgram.c) for an audio stream
- ["Sound Activated Recorder with Spectrogram in C#"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22951/Sound-Activated-Recorder-with-Spectrogram-in-C) by Jeff Morton
- [Topographica](http://topographica.org/) seems to include [spectrogram source code](http://topographica.org/Reference_Manual/topo.pattern.basic.Spectrogram-class.html)
- [SpectroGraph for iTunes](http://www.dr-lex.be/software/spectrograph.html)

[Image to Spectrogram](http://devrand.org/view/imageSpectrogram) goes in the reverse direction from the above utilities.

Answer (score 1):

you could use fftw (fftw.org) to calculate the spectrogram, you would still need to plot the data, but that should not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFT code from [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-simple-and-efficient-fft-implementatio/199500857). It uses C++ template metaprogramming for efficiency. The full source is provided by the author [here](http://twimgs.com/ddj/images/article/2007/code/myrnyy_fft_source_code.zip).

It was [suggested](http://listengine.tuxfamily.org/lists.tuxfamily.org/eigen/2008/11/msg00001.html) to include this code into Eigen for its use of templated (type friendly) code.