# Plotting the spectrogram

Tags: c++, fftw, spectrogram

Using the answer to this link:[Spectrogram C++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133651/spectrogram-c-library) I have written a code to calculate the spectrogram of a sinusoidal signal:
1-Created a sinusoidal signal.
2- I applied the Hann Window.
3- used FFTW .
4- Calculated log magnitude of frequency coefficients.
Here is the script:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double y;
    int N=256;
    double Fs=30000;//sampling frequency
    double  T=1/Fs;//sample time 
    double f=5000;//frequency
    double *in;
    fftw_complex *out;
    double t[N-1];//time vector 
    fftw_plan plan_forward;

    in = (double*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    for (int i=0; i< N;i++)
    {
        t[i]=i*T;
        in[i] =0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);// generate sine waveform
        double multiplier = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*M_PI*i/(N-1)));//Hanning Window
        in[i] = multiplier * in[i];
    }

    plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d ( N, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE );

    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "  Input Data:\n" );
    printf ( "\n" );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "  %4d  %12f\n", i, in[i] );
    }

    fftw_execute ( plan_forward );

    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "  log magnitude of frequency domain components :\n" );
    printf ( "\n" );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cout << log(sqrt(out[i][0]*out[i][0]+ out[i][1]*out[i][1])) ;

    }
    fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_forward );
    fftw_free ( in );
    fftw_free ( out );
    return 0;
}
```

The question is how should I proceed from here? Which library should I use to plot the spectrogram? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay with C++ and be reasonable cross-platform, you might want to consider Qt as UI and either Qwt or QCustomPlot ar scientific plots widget

Links

http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/

http://www.qcustomplot.com/